# 'set' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь освоить Django, шаг за шагом. На этапе создания миграции возникает ошибка **'set' object has no attribute 'get'**. База данных MSSQL server 2005 ExpressEdition. Настройки в Django следующие:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'press_data_collect',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost\WINCCFLEXEXPRESS',
        'PORT': '',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',

        },
    },
}
```

Собственно ошибка в файле base.py:

```
    if 'driver_needs_utf8' in opts:
        self.driver_charset = 'utf-8'
    else:
        self.driver_charset = opts.get('driver_charset', None) #в этой строке
```

Пробовал в опциях настройки database добавить строку :
'driver_supports_utf8': True,
думал что как-то с кодировкой связано, но тогда ругается на синтаксис данной строки, хотя некоторые прям так и вставляют.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

1. `{ 'key': 'value' }` - словарь
2. `{ 'value' }` - множество

У словаря есть метод `get`, у множества нет.

Comment: self.driver_charset = opts.get('driver_charset':'None') такой синтаксис тоже не рабочий, да и странно, сам файл base.py из модуля django-mssql-backend, и надо полагать уже обкатан.

Comment: @AleksandrLeonov думаю речь о строчке в setings.py ` 'driver' :'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'`

Comment: если не указывать драйвер, тогда ошибка "Data source name not found and not default driver specified"

Comment: @AleksandrLeonov я имел ввиду что у вас нет `'driver'` в `OPTIONS`

Comment: @AleksandrLeonov вам стоит очень внимательно перечитать [документацию](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/#options).

Comment: Всем спасибо, проблема была в неправильном выборе драйвера ODBC: 'driver' :'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' .оказался корректным вместо 'driver' :'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'. Зашел в коyфигурацию ODBC, а у меня 13 и не установлен был..

Comment: @AleksandrLeonov вам два человека написали, что проблема в отсутствии ключа `driver` у словаря `OPTIONS`.